# What's difference between using AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper and AWSDynamoDB?

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Both of these classes may be used to access a DynamoDB. In what cases would I use one over the other, when using the iOS SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two lines :

AWSDynamoDB is a DynamoDB API client class.
AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper is a higher level object, a database persistence framework.

**AWSDynamoDB**

This class wraps the DynamoDB API.  You provide methods of this class with a DynamoDBRequest object that describes the operation you want to perform, and it will return a Response object that describe s the result of your request or an error, if any.
This low level and mostly match the DynamoDB HTTP API

**AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper**

When using AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper, you create a class that represent the item you want to store / retrieve from the database.  Then you pass instances of this class to higher level methods such as `save()`, `delete()` etc...

This is a much higher level of abstraction.  Similar in philosophy to Object Relational frameworks such as Hibernate for example.

More details and code sample in Objective C are available here :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html

I also posted a Swift code sample when answering this question :
[Best way to make Amazon AWS DynamoDB queries using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958637/best-way-to-make-amazon-aws-dynamodb-queries-using-swift/26964281#26964281)