# Best way to make Amazon AWS DynamoDB queries using Swift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I have recently implemented the AWS SDK for my iOS app, which I am developing in Swift. I have connected to my DB instance and am able to get a query response, however, I am struggling to convert this into usable data. I'm relatively new to Swift, AWS and programming in general so maybe missing something obvious!

My code is as follows:

```
    let atVal = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    atVal.S = "123456abc"
    let condition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
    condition.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.EQ
    condition.attributeValueList = [atVal]

    let myDic: [String: AWSDynamoDBCondition] = ["userid": condition]
    let query = AWSDynamoDBQueryInput()
    query.indexName = "userid-index"
    query.tableName = "users"
    query.keyConditions = myDic
    query.limit = 1


    dynamoDB.query(query).continueWithBlock {
        (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        let results = task.result as AWSDynamoDBQueryOutput

        let myResults = results.items
        println("object: \(myResults.description)")

        return nil
    }
```

And the console output for this is:

object: [{
    area = " {\n    S = \"West Hampstead\";\n}";
    name = " {\n    S = \"Olly Mayes\";\n}";
    userid = " {\n    S = \"123456abc\";\n}";
}]

There doesn't seem to be much precedence for using AWS and Swift, understandably, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easy answer to your question is : convert the JSON string returned into a Dictionary object.
Something like this :

```
let data = jsonDataItem.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    if data != nil {
        var error : NSError?
        let dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? NSDictionary

        if let e = error {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
```

However, I would strongly encourage you to look at the higher level DynamoDB mapper class
When using DynamoDB mapper class, you define your data structure, and just give it to [DynamoDB Mapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html).  Here is a full sample, from table creation to table deletion.  The example inserts, removes, scans and query the table using DynamoDB Mapper.

First, you need to initialise the client SDK

```
    let cp = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: "AK...", secretKey: "xxx")
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: cp)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().setDefaultServiceConfiguration(configuration)
```

This is a sample only.  It is not a good practice to embed an Access Key and Secret Key in the code.  Best practice would be to use the [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider.html) instead ([read more about Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/cognito-auth.html)).

**Define a class that maps your items in the table**

```
class Item : AWSDynamoDBModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

    var email  : String = ""
    var date   : String = ""
    var note   : String = ""
    var number : Double = 0.0

    override init!() { super.init() }

    required init!(coder: NSCoder!) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
        return "Demo"
    }
    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "email"
    }
    class func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String! {
        return "date"
    }

    //required to let DynamoDB Mapper create instances of this class
    override init(dictionary dictionaryValue: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: NSErrorPointer) {
        super.init(dictionary: dictionaryValue, error: error)
    }

    //workaround to possible XCode 6.1 Bug : "Type NotificationAck" does not conform to protocol "NSObjectProtocol"
    override func isEqual(anObject: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return super.isEqual(anObject)
    } }
```

**To create a table**

```
self.createTable().continueWithSuccessBlock {(task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
    NSLog("Create table - success")
    return nil
}


func createTable() -> BFTask! {
    let pt = AWSDynamoDBProvisionedThroughput()
    pt.readCapacityUnits  = 10
    pt.writeCapacityUnits = 10

    let emailAttr = AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition()
    emailAttr.attributeName = "email"
    emailAttr.attributeType = AWSDynamoDBScalarAttributeType.S

    let dateAttr = AWSDynamoDBAttributeDefinition()
    dateAttr.attributeName = "date"
    dateAttr.attributeType = AWSDynamoDBScalarAttributeType.S

    let emailKey = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    emailKey.attributeName = "email"
    emailKey.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Hash

    let dateKey = AWSDynamoDBKeySchemaElement()
    dateKey.attributeName = "date"
    dateKey.keyType = AWSDynamoDBKeyType.Range

    let ct = AWSDynamoDBCreateTableInput()
    ct.tableName = "Demo"
    ct.provisionedThroughput = pt
    ct.attributeDefinitions = [emailAttr, dateAttr]
    ct.keySchema = [ emailKey, dateKey ]

    NSLog("Creating table")

    let client = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()
    return client.createTable(ct)
}
```

**To delete a table**

```
self.deleteTable().continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
    NSLog("Delete table - success")
    return nil
})

func deleteTable() -> BFTask! {

    let dt = AWSDynamoDBDeleteTableInput()
    dt.tableName = "Demo"

    NSLog("Deleting table")
    let client = AWSDynamoDB.defaultDynamoDB()
    return client.deleteTable(dt)
}
```

**To insert items**

```
self.insertSomeItems().continueWithBlock({
    (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in

    if (task.error != nil) {
        NSLog(task.error.description)
    } else {
        NSLog("DynamoDB save succeeded")
    }

    return nil;
})

func insertSomeItems() -> BFTask! {
    let mapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    var item = Item()
    item.email  = "stormacq@amazon.com"
    item.date   = "20141101"
    item.note   = "This is item #1"
    item.number = 1.0
    let task1 = mapper.save(item)

    item = Item()
    item.email  = "stormacq@amazon.com"
    item.date   = "20141102"
    item.note   = "This is item #2"
    item.number = 2.0
    let task2 = mapper.save(item)

    item = Item()
    item.email  = "stormacq@amazon.lu"
    item.date   = "20141103"
    item.note   = "This is item #3"
    item.number = 3.0
    let task3 = mapper.save(item)

    return BFTask(forCompletionOfAllTasks: [task1, task2, task3])
}
```

**To load one single item**

```
self.load("stormacq@amazon.com", range:"20141101").continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
    NSLog("Load one value - success")
    let item = task.result as Item
    print(item)
    return nil
})


func load(hash: String, range: String) -> BFTask! {
    let mapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
    return mapper.load(Item.self, hashKey: hash, rangeKey: range)

}
```

**To query on hash and range key**

```
/* 
   keyConditions
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBQueryInput.html#//api/name/keyConditions
*/
let cond = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
let v1    = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue(); v1.S = "20141101"
cond.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.EQ
cond.attributeValueList = [ v1 ]
let c = [ "date" : cond ]
self.query("stormacq@amazon.com", keyConditions:c).continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
    NSLog("Query multiple values - success")
    let results = task.result as AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
    for r in results.items {
        print(r)
    }
    return nil
})

func query(hash: String, keyConditions:[NSObject:AnyObject]) -> BFTask! {
    let mapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    let exp = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()
    exp.hashKeyValues      = hash
    exp.rangeKeyConditions = keyConditions

    return mapper.query(Item.self, expression: exp)
}
```

**To scan items (full table scan)**

```
let cond = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
let v1    = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue(); v1.S = "20141101"
cond.comparisonOperator = AWSDynamoDBComparisonOperator.GT
cond.attributeValueList = [ v1 ]

let exp = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
exp.scanFilter = [ "date" : cond ]

self.scan(exp).continueWithSuccessBlock({ (task: BFTask!) -> BFTask! in
    NSLog("Scan multiple values - success")
    let results = task.result as AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput
    for r in results.items {
        print(r)
    }
    return nil
})

func scan(expression : AWSDynamoDBScanExpression) -> BFTask! {

    let mapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()
    return mapper.scan(Item.self, expression: expression)
}
```

If you have no other usage of DynamoDB in US EAST 1, there is no cost associated with running this sample, as it is falling into [DynamoDB's free tier](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried both methods and not managed to get the result I'm after. The first seems to be failing because the returned JSON is not actually a properly formed JSON.

I would like to get the object mapper working if possible, do you know how this would work if the action was 'query' instead of 'save'?

To be clear I'd like to query against the users table using the userid field - this is not the primary index, it is a secondary index - and I would like to get back the 'area' for this user.

Comment: Yes you can query using the mapper too.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.html#//api/name/query:expression:  I will try to make you an example if I have time tonight

Comment: I've tried this a few times and no luck! Do you think you could show a simple example? I'll paste what I've done already when I'm back to my development machine...

Comment: This is a pure SWIFT error, not an AWS one. This is because your task.result does not contain value ... do you have an item "156" in your table ?  To avoid that runtime error, use conditional casting : let item = task.result as? DBItem (note the question mark)

Comment: Any idea how to do this with a secondary index?

Comment: This answer is a really great overview of Dynamo DB methods in swift, thanks!

Comment: After updating to Xcode 7.0, I received the following message: "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass" for the override init(dictionary dictionaryValue: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: NSErrorPointer) metho. I replaced it with:     override init(dictionary dictionaryValue: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: ()) throws {
        do {
            try super.init(dictionary: dictionaryValue, error: error)
        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }
    }

Comment: I have written a tutorial series about using AWS (including DynamoDB) as a backend for a Swift app. http://peterfennema.nl/exploring-aws-as-a-backend-for-a-swift-app-1/

Comment: @SébastienStormacq is this a secure way to access the db? if I were to store login credentials here would they be safe?

Comment: IAM Roles are the way to go : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/authentication-and-access-control.html

Comment: @SébastienStormacq great answer, thank you for it. (1) Will this work with DynamoDB results through AppSync? (2) Do you prefer the AWS mapper to a native Swift parser?

Comment: (1) this is not necessary if you are using AppSync.  AppSync uses resolvers on the server side to map DynamoDB's results to the API result.  There is not need to use the DynamoDB client in Swift in that case. Check the App Sync iOS SDK at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-ios (2) I wrote the above answer 4 years ago, before Swift had a decent support for JSON.  I should re-write this answer for Swift4 and the JSONSerialization object.