# DynamoDB Swift Table Scan Mapping Class

Tags: swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do a simple table scan with AWS and DynamoDB using Swift. I am new to apple programming and not sure what the issue is. The documentation for AWS SDK is all in objective C and the examples AWS give for Swift are rubbish.

The best info I got was from a question here so I have been trying to work through it.

[Best way to make Amazon AWS DynamoDB queries using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958637/best-way-to-make-amazon-aws-dynamodb-queries-using-swift)

There are too many error for one question so I will break it up into multiple questions:

The first part I tried to do is my class item which defines the mapping from the database "Item"

I have written my code and the errors I am getting underneath each line in bold:

```
    class Item : NSObject, AWSDynamoDBModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {
```

**'Item' does not conform to protocol 'AWSDynamoDBModeling'**

```
        var Artist              :   String = ""
        var SongTitle           :   String = ""
        var AlbumTitle          :   String = ""
        var Category            :   String = ""
        var PictureURL          :   String = ""
        var SongURL             :   String = ""
        var Location            :   String = ""
        var AVGMusicianRating   :   Int = 0
        var AVGUserRating       :   Int = 0
        var SongDuration        :   Int = 0
        var SongID              :   Int = 0

        override init!() { super.init() }
```

**Failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable initializer**

```
        required init!(coder:    NSCoder!) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String! {
            return "Songs"
        }
        class func hashKeyAttribute() -> Int! {
            return SongID
        }
```

**Instance member 'SongID' cannot be used on type 'Item' (My hash Key is an int not string)**

```
        //required to let DynamoDB Mapper create instances of this class
        override init(dictionary dictionaryValue: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, error: NSErrorPointer)
```

**Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass**

```
        {
                super.init(dictionary: dictionaryValue, error: error)
            }

            //workaround to possible XCode 6.1 Bug : "Type NotificationAck" does not conform to protocol "NSObjectProtocol"
            override func isEqual(anObject: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
                return super.isEqual(anObject)
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. 'Item' does not conform to protocol 'AWSDynamoDBModeling'**

Replace

```
class func hashKeyAttribute() -> Int! {
    return SongID
}
```

By

```
class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String! {
    return "SongID"
}
```

Explanation: You need to provide the name of the hashkey attribute, not it's type. The protocol requires that you return a String.

**2. Failable initializer 'init()' cannot override a non-failable
    initializer**

There is no need to extend NSObject. You can remove all init(..) methods from your code. As far as I can see they are not needed.

**3. Instance member 'SongID' cannot be used on type 'Item' (My hash Key
    is an int not string)**

This will go away when you fix error 1.

**4. Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its
    superclass**

This will go away when you fix error 2

I wrote a [tutorial](http://peterfennema.nl/exploring-aws-as-a-backend-for-a-swift-app-1/) about using DynamoDB for a Swift app. [Part 3](http://peterfennema.nl/exploring-aws-as-a-backend-for-a-swift-app-3/) contains a simple example of a class AMZUser that is mapped to DynamoDB

Comment: Thanks for your help this does answer the question I asked. I have tried using your tutorial but unfortunately I have to do a full table scan. So I am forced to go back and work out how to do it in objective C. For such a large company you would think AWS could work out documentation that is relevant to the current standards.